# Scala Actor subclass can't access mailboxSize?

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor

I have some code like this:

```
package something

import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

class Foo extends Actor {
  private val random = new Random()

  def doWork() {
    if (self.mailboxSize >= 3) {
      println("Actor loaded, use another node")
    } else {
      doSomething()
   }
 }
... more code
}
```

And when I try to compile it (fsc *.scala), I get:

```
error: method mailboxSize in trait Reactor cannot be accessed in scala.actors.Actor
 Access to protected method mailboxSize not permitted because
 prefix type scala.actors.Actor does not conform to
 class Foo in package something where the access take place
```

mailboxSize is protected, but I should be able to access it in a subclass right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
this.mailboxSize
```

Sorry, but can't check it right now.